# is it possible to auto-generate annotated POJO from a table

Tags: java, orm, annotations

I wonder is it possible or is there a tool to generate annotated POJOs from a table.To make it clear,for example,Person table has fields like ,id,name,surname etc and i wanna to generate a POJO named Person with mappings made with annotations.

Comment: Many, if not all, ORM tools do this. Same for most UML tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the answer to this SO question in the past, and it worked fairly well for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384433/hibernate-tool-to-create-basic-mappings-based-on-a-mysql-db